# severeal mails sent from my contact form what is wrong?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, submit

as i said my form is working, but when i submit the data it sends the mail twice. the data is recibed in index.php and the is sent to contact. php, this is the form in index.php

```
 <form name="sentMessage" action="index.php" id="contactForm" method="POST"  novalidate="novalidate">
                  <div class="control-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor ingrese su nombre" />
                      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Ingrese su Email" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor ingrese su email" />
                      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Ingrese un asunto" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor elija un curso" />
                      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Ingrese su mensaje" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor ingrese su mensaje"></textarea>
                      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                      <button class="btn" name="enviar" type="submit" id="sendMessageButton" onClick="clearform();">Enviar mensaje</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
```

this is the code in contact.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && $_POST['email'] !==''){
  if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['subject']) || !empty($_POST['message']) || filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
  $email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
  $m_subject = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

$to = "pepito@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "$m_subject:  $name";
$body = "recibiste un nuevo email desde la pagina de Fácil Soft.\n\n"."detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\n\nEmail: $email\n\nAsunto: $m_subject\n\nMensaje: $message";

mail($to, $subject , $body);

 if(!mail($to, $subject, $body))
  http_response_code(500);
  exit();
 }
}
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

Comment: You're calling `mail()` twice. Each one sends a mail. You can just get rid of the first one in this case.

Comment: I think you need to change the code:
mail($to, $subject , $body); //code execution

 if(!mail($to, $subject, $body)) // condition executes the operation and then based on response next steps are executed.

Comment: thank you both sorry for ask that  basic question but im still learning